# How to disable auto editing of NSOutlineView

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nsoutlineview

I'm working on an app with NSOutlineView.
The outline view is view-based and is initialized programmatically like:

```swift
    internal lazy var outlineView: NSOutlineView = {
        let outlineView = NSOutlineView()
        outlineView.usesAutomaticRowHeights = true

        let column = NSTableColumn(identifier: .listOutlineColumn)
        outlineView.addTableColumn(column)
        outlineView.outlineTableColumn = column

        outlineView.headerView = nil
        outlineView.backgroundColor = .clear
        outlineView.indentationPerLevel = 16
        outlineView.allowsEmptySelection = false
        outlineView.refusesFirstResponder = true
        outlineView.style = .sourceList

        return outlineView
    }()
```

The problem is when I'm editing a row like `List 11`, if I tap the row `New List 2` the new row is in editing mode immediately (and all text is selected).
What I want is just to end the editing and select the new row.

Could somebody tell me how to do this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which view should be first responder?

Comment: @Willeke The first responder is set to another outline view

Comment: Please, provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Works as expected for me.

Comment: @zrzka Thanks for helping!
I've created a gist for full source code at https://gist.github.com/waynezhang/c8e0b42c809c51a984401c890399989f

Comment: Also I uploaded the whole project at https://filebin.net/sqh6zwchvgeq6r9h.
Thanks!

Comment: I found it works if the `refusesFirstResponder` is set to `false`. Is there any workaround to get it work even `refusesFirstResponder` is `true`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, if the `refusesFirstResponder` of outline view is set to `false`, this property of `NSTextField` inside the `NSTableCellView` should also be set to `false`.
And if a customized cell of `NSTextField` is used, this `refusesFirstResponder` property should also be set.